# Send data to the server in service class

Tags: java, android, service, httpurlconnection

I am trying to send data to server when user mobile internet become active, in my application whenever internet connection is active my broadcast receiver call a service method.
Below is the method. I trying for both post and get method but it does not request to the site. I am not able to print "i am in service5"(Below i have printed).It does not update my database.

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
....
....
public void sendfeedback(){



        System.out.println("i am in service4");
        String filename =MainScreenActivity.UserName;


        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        final String target_uri =
                "http://readoline.com/feedback.php";






        try {
            BufferedReader mReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getApplicationContext().openFileInput(filename)));
            String line;
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();


            while ((line = mReader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }
            System.out.println(buffer.toString());


            try {
                System.out.println("i am in service41"+buffer.toString());
                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse("http://readoline.com/feedback.php" + "?").buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter("user_id", filename)
                        .appendQueryParameter("feedback", buffer.toString())
                        .build();

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());



                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                System.out.println("i am in service44");
            /*  PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                out.write("user_id="+filename);
                out.write("&");
                out.write("feedback="+buffer.toString());
            */
                    System.out.println("i am in service5");


                //  Log.e(LOG_TAG,dataToSend.toString());


                //out.close();
                // Read the input stream into a String


            }catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("i am in service6");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                if (urlConnection!=null){
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }



        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where u startservice ???

Comment: I started the service in one of my class and able to print System.out.println("i am in service4"); so i am sure method is called properly.

Comment: Check internet service

Comment: Do i need to check internet in the service? if yes so this method is call only when internet is active

Comment: how starting the service

Comment: i have started the service by startService() in one of my class and is that matter now if i specify that service method is calls properly?

Comment: Why don't you try using Volley for sending data back to server https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html

Comment: Is that work continuously forever and works even when application is closed?

Comment: Nope but use it to send data to server in a service. Its much simpler just 3 lines of code